# Change style to all HTMLcolection with JS

Tags: javascript, html, collections, nodes

I have an HTML collection and i want to change to all the collection at the same time howcan I do it that but in a single line?? imagenEnsaladas(HMLT COLECTION  of list items)

```
imgSalad.src = carruselPhotos[positionCarrusel];
    carruselLi[0].style.backgroundColor = "#1a1d20";
    carruselLi[1].style.backgroundColor = "#1a1d20";
    carruselLi[2].style.backgroundColor = "#1a1d20";
    carruselLi[3].style.backgroundColor = "#1a1d20";
    carruselLi[4].style.backgroundColor = "#1a1d20";
    carruselLi[positionCarrusel].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Comment: A `for` loop, a style that depends on a class on a common parent element, ... -> What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: I try to set to HTMLcolection set the back ground  like that  carruselLi.style.backgroundColor = "#1a1d20";(with out position)  nd a for loop that is not working as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can do this like this with a for loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < carruselLi.length; i++) {
if (i === positionCarrusel) {
    carruselLi[positionCarrusel].style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
} else {
    carruselLi[i].style.backgroundColor = "#1a1d20";
}
```

}

Comment: It's working  very good, let me check if I understand, the else statement it's working becouse is reading all the array while it's setting the background color?

Comment: well both conditions are reading all array, just the first conditions checks if it is the element you are looking to make other change, if this doesn't match then that current li will be default, with this color #1a1d20